# Open secure browser with Protractor

Tags: security, browser, protractor

For my test I need to use secure browser - needs to be run as an application (single exe file) and it lunches to designated site in kiosk mode (disables task switching). Once I'm there it's Angular page so I think it should work but I don't know how to lunch secure browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think this is possibe right now. protractor needs browser specific drivers. have a look at [protractor browser support](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#browser-support).